# Prefetching in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

In one page of my application I'm letting the user filter through their entries stored in Core Data to let them see a more refined picture of their data. I want to prefetch all the entries the user will be able to filter through in the `viewDidLoad()` so I don't have to do the initial fetch every time the user changes the filter parameters. Right now I'm fetching all the entries every time the user requests to see their filtered data like this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: Event.entityName)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "toPet.dbName == %@", self.currentPet)
request.predicate = predicate

do {
    let results = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)       
} catch {}
```

Is it possible to later make a new fetch request on the results from the above request?

Comment: You could have a separate `filteredResults` array, which you populate each time by filtering the `results` array, rather than by executing a new fetch.

Comment: Got it, I wonder how much faster it would be doing that and using `.map` or `.filter` to filter out the results instead of refetching each time.

Comment: Difficult to say.  If you try it, do specify "toPet" as a `relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` in the initial fetch of Events.  It will ensure that the relevant Pet objects are fetched in one go.  Otherwise the first .filter will trigger each Pet to be loaded individually, which will definitely be slower.